# Configure NAT on router PC

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, ubuntu-12.04

I have a problem with NAT configuration. I made my laptop to be a router, using Ubuntu 12.04. In the terminal, I typed:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

but the client still has not been able to connect to the Internet, when interfacing the router (my laptop) to a client using a LAN cable. But the client is able to ping the router.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your NAT firewall rule is OK but by default ubuntu is not forwarding packets so you need to enable that with:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To make it automatic, you can use a script like this (save in `/etc/init.d/your-script`):

```
#!/bin/sh
# turn ip_forward on/off

case "$1" in
'start')
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        ;;
'stop')
        echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        ;;
*)
        echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop }"
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

And make it executable and run on boot with:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/your-script
sudo update-rc.d your-script defaults
```

To enable: `sudo /etc/init.d/your-script start` and `sudo /etc/init.d/your-script stop` to disable.

UPDATE:
As Paul commented, if you prefer, to make it permanent (or if you feel comfortable editing the conf file to turn this feature on/off) you can modify `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment the line with `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to enable and comment out to disable.

Comment: Please don't make a script to do this, just edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: Sure for permanent config, sysctl.conf is better but that depends on the use, if he wants to be able to turn it on and off (as it is a laptop and he may not want to forward everywhere), a script is easier (and he has the option to not enable it on boot too if he wants).

Comment: Sure - for completeness, why not edit and include the sysctl option as well as the script option.

Comment: I have tried but the client still can't connect to the internet

Comment: Is ppp0 the interface connected to the internet and have you configured the laptop firewall to accept and forward everything (or less if you need but at least what is received on port 80) on the local interface?

Comment: Is your firewall `masquerade` line appearing with `iptables -L`? If not you need to save it in a script or conf file and load iptables at boot or networking start (many possible ways init.d or if-up.d scripts or load it in `/etc/network/interfaces` for example)